# Continuity of an inverse probability function

Tags: probability

I have a question about the continuity of a specific defined function. So, if I define $\tilde F(t) = \inf\{x: F(x) \geq t\}$. And F is a distribution function. Is this $\tilde F$ always right continuous?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. Let $F(x)=0$ for $x <1$, $\frac 1 2 $ for $1 \leq x <2$ and $1$ for $x \geq 2$. Then $\tilde F(t)=2$ for all $t >\frac 1 2$ but $\tilde F(\frac 1 2)=1$.

Comment: Thanks a lot! But what if I change the definition to $\tilde F(t) = \inf\{x: F(x) > t\}$? Is this $\tilde F$ right continuous?

Comment: @Jiexiong687691 Yes, this new function is right continuous.